# Unlock bootloader using Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: root-access, tablet, bootloader

I'm trying to root the device name: Overmax SteelCore 10+ to install ubuntu touch. When i use

> $ adb devices

sometimes i get:

> 0123456789ABCDEF DEVICE
>
> and when i type to reboot bootloader (teblet go off and on, nnormal boot android) and i get:
>
> 0123456789ABCDEF OFLINE

So i power off and on device to get not off line and try to

> $ sudo fastboot oem unlock

And im stuck on waiting for device on tablet screen nothing shows up to accept. I have only recovery when i press volume "-" and power bution. Please help ;__;

Comment: You can't use fastboot if the tablet is booted into normal Android. It needs to be booted into fastboot mode.

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu Touch supports your device? We can't help with the Ubuntu part here, but I do know it only supports a limited set of popular devices.

Comment: I know is not suported device. When i is on fastboot mode the device is offline i try to root this tablet thats the main problem to root and unlock this tablet

Comment: Why bother if you won't be able to install Ubuntu Touch anyway? Besides, you **don't** need to root the device to install another OS, just to unlock the bootloader. Whatever `adb` says about the device is irrelevant, as `fastboot` is completely separate. Does the device show up in `fastboot devices` **when it is booted into fastboot mode**, not Android?

Comment: How to unlock bootloader? I just root using Kingo root it's add icon Super SU thats all still can't get to bottloader inly recovery when i use fastboot oem unlock stuck on waitng for device. I have only recovy still.

Comment: Also i try to install original update from overmax using recovery and nope. Thats funny because i instal Onda_Allwinner_A31_root_v1_0 on recovery and install normaly...

Comment: Does it shows up as device if you use 'fasboot devices' in fastboot mode? can you boot into fastboot with any of the power/Vol combinations?